# While using connected-react-router, router reducer isn't found

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, router, connected-react-router

This is my store.ts

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootSaga from 'sagas';
import rootReducer from 'reducers';
import { history } from 'common/helpers/historyHelper';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';

declare global {
  interface Window { // eslint-disable-line
    __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose; // eslint-disable-line
  }
}
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer(),
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)))
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

rootReducer.ts

```
import { history } from 'common/helpers/historyHelper';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import user from 'scenes/Auth/reducers/user';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';

const rootReducer = () => combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  user
});

export default rootReducer;
```

rootSaga.ts

```
import authSaga from 'scenes/Auth/sagas';
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    authSaga()
  ]);
}
```

historyHelper.ts

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../../store';
import { Page } from 'containers/Page';
import { history } from 'common/helpers/historyHelper';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Page />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

And when I click some link to change a route, I see, that path is changing in my browser, also in redux-devtools, but components don't switch and I get an error you can see below.
I also see router reducer in Redux-devtools.
I don't have any ideas how to fix it.

[image: Redux-devtools image]

[image: Error image]

Comment: Try to show your error in text rather in picture, avoid posting photos whenever you can to increase readability.

Comment: Have you checked `selectors.js` line 17? If you click on the link the source should load in the dev tools.

Comment: @DrewReese I don't have file selectors.js